# Webclient (Connection pooling & SSL handshake)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

In Spring 5, we are using webclient to call other REST endpoints over SSL. When we took the logs on wireshark, we saw that for each request, SSL handshake is happening and it is taking a lot of time.

These are the queries I have.

Query 1:
Webclient does internal pooling of connection. What is the expiry time after which the connection would be invalidated.

Can we set the time for which the connection should be open for sending new request on the already defined connection to avoid SSL handshake ?

Is there a setting to avoid SSL handshake for every request ?

Query 2:
We are creating the bean of Webclient and are using that across the application. Is there some setting that we need to do to enable connection pooling and reuse of the existing connection for sending new requests. Also any setting to avoid SSL handshake every time.

```
    @Bean(name="productDefWebClient")
    public WebClient productDefWebClient() {
        ConnectionProvider elasticPool = ConnectionProvider.elastic("productDef-pool");
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(elasticPool).wiretap(true);
        return WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .defaultHeader("Accept","application/json")
                .baseUrl("https://test-qa.test.com")
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: Did you find the way forcing WebClient to re-use connection from the pool in case of SSL connections ?

Comment: Look at the value of response header `Keep-Alive`, that might be the problem.

Also, have you tried with the default `WebClient` (without customizing `HttpClient`), does it have the same behavior?